# formula to select a year using crystal

Tags: crystal-reports

I've created a Crystal Report that uses formulas in the Running Totals calculation.

```
    {OINV.DocDate} in DateTime (2018, 01, 01, 00, 00, 00) to DateTime (2018, 01, 
31, 00, 00, 00)
```

However, I've included the year in the crystal syntax, now the report is only relevant for 2018. I'm struggling to create a formula that 1st, would be input by the user (ex: 2017 or 2018) and used in the **record selection criteria**.

Year Formula: `year ({OINV.DocDate})`

Next, I've created an input parameter for the user to enter the report "Year" and pull only records equal to the entered year.

1st - I converted OINV.DocDate to a string.

**Formula**: `ToText ({OINV.DocDate})` **Formula Name**: "year to string"

Next, since the year is the first 4 positions, I created the next formula to pull only the year.

**Formula**: `Left ({@year to string}, 4)` **Formula Name:** "year to string 2"

In the record selection criteria, formula to pull only entered year records:

```
{@year to string 2} = {?Year}
```

The main problem would be, how to edit the running totals formula to replace the hard coded year with the new formula that defines the selected year.

Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not use images to convey textual information. [Edit] your question to replace them with the respective code. Additionally, questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Without this, your question is off-topic and liable to be closed. Please construct a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and include it.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    {OINV.DocDate} in DateTime (ToNumber({?Year}), 01, 01, 00, 00, 00) to DateTime
 (ToNumber({?Year}), 01, 31, 00, 00, 00)
```

one suggestion here is instead of parameter as a string take parameter as `Integer` which will make your logic much simplier